# Causing an EOF error when function is run - using Python

Tags: python, eof

I'm working on a project for a college course, with different prompts we need to fulfill in functionality. I'm not looking for the rest of the code I haven't completed yet to be solved, just trying to figure out how to be able to keep prompting the user for an input after the get_num_of_words() function is called, without getting an EOF error. One important thing to note, on the assignment we were explicitly told to avoid using pre-existing functions.

code is provided below:

```
def get_num_of_words(user_input):
    count = 0
    words = 0
    length = 0
    for i in user_input:
        length += 1
    while count < length:
        if user_input[count] == user_input[-1]:
            words += 1
        elif user_input[count] != ' ' and user_input[count + 1] == ' ':
            words += 1
        else:
            pass
        count += 1
    print('Number of words:', str(words) + '\n')
    return words
    

def get_num_of_non_WS_characters(user_input):
    count = 0
    for i in user_input:
        if i == ' ':
            pass
        else:
            count += 1
    print('Number of non-whitespace characters:', str(count) + '\n')
    return count
    

def menu_prompt():
    print_menu()
    selection = input('Choose an option:\n')
    while selection != 'q' and selection != 'c' and selection != 'w' and selection != 'f' and selection != 'r' and selection != 's':
        selection = input('Choose an option:\n')
    return selection
    
def execute_menu(selection, user_input):
    if selection == 'q':
        pass
    elif selection == 'c':
        get_num_of_non_WS_characters(user_input)
        execute_menu(menu_prompt(), user_input)
    elif selection == 'w':
        get_num_of_words(user_input)
        execute_menu(menu_prompt(), user_input)
    #elif selection == 'f':
        print_menu()
    #elif selection == 'r':
        #print_menu()
    #elif selection == 's':
        #print_menu()
        
def print_menu():
    print('MENU\nc - Number of non-whitespace characters\nw - Number of words\nf - Fix capitalization\nr - Replace punctuation\ns - Shorten spaces\nq - Quit\n')
    
    
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_input = input('Enter a sample text:\n')
    print()
    print('You entered:', user_input)
    print()
    execute_menu(menu_prompt(), user_input)
```

I've tried only calling menu_prompt() after the get_num_of_words() function, but while that prints what I want, I already know that it won't actually go on to do anything with the received input, though it doesn't give an error either. The way the code currently is, what it prints so far, is properly formatted. Might just be the kind of mindset you can get with a rubik's cube after completing a side, you don't want to undo the work you've already done, but you need to take a step back to make 2 steps forward. I just can't shake that hesitancy I suppose.

Comment: can't walk - crawl!

Answer (score 0):

Add while loop inside your main And add return statement in execute_menu() Because you are calling function as many time as user is giving input and hence code is giving error:

```
def execute_menu(selection, user_input):
if selection == 'q':
    pass
elif selection == 'c':
    get_num_of_non_WS_characters(user_input)
    return
elif selection == 'w':
    get_num_of_words(user_input)
    return
#elif selection == 'f':
    #print_menu()
#elif selection == 'r':
    #print_menu()
#elif selection == 's':
    #print_menu()
return    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_input = input('Enter a sample text:\n')
    print()
    print('You entered:', user_input)
    print()
    ch = menu_prompt()
    while ch != 'q':
        execute_menu(ch, user_input)
        ch = menu_prompt()
```

Comment: Alright, thank you very much! Can’t help but feel a little silly for missing something like that haha, but that really helps out a bunch!